# Getting the Error while launching Visual Studio 2019, the same is the result when I install Visual 2017 as well.Can I get a assistance

Tags: .net

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfUup.png)

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Could not start visual studio due to an error.

StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException:

Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)

---

### OK